# Using OpenSSL with Intel SGX Enclave

Tags: visual-studio-2012, openssl, intel

I am currently developing a Intel SGX Application. And I need to use OpenSSL library in the enclave. However, when I build the enclave, tons of errors appear. 
They looks like this:

```
Error   17  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FILE'   C:\OpenSSL-Win32\include\openssl\asn1.h 994 1   Enclave
```

I am not sure if I configure the enclave correctly.

```
VC++ Directories --> Include Directories "C://OpenSSL-Win32/include"
                     Library Directories "C://OpenSSL-Win32/lib"
C/C++ --> Additional Include Directories "(some SGX default); C://OpenSSL-Win32/include"
Linker --> General --> Additional Library Directories "C://OpenSSL-Win32/lib"
           Input --> Additional Dependencies: "libeay32.lib; ssleay32.lib"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should probably either (1) configure OpenSSL with `no-stdio` if you are not using it; or (2) include `<stdio.h>` on Windows for `FILE` (or `<unistd.h>` on Linux).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the same end, I ported [`mbedtls`](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls) to the SGX environment. The ported version is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/bl4ck5un/mbedtls-SGX). Feel free to checkout.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Intel trusted OpenSSL library ? There is a sample code "X509 project" that shows how to use the trusted OpenSSL (topenssl) inside enclaves.
If you want to use another version of OpenSSL you should build it with Intel trusted standard C/C++ libraries and create an "enclave library" then link it to the enclave. You can not link the enclave with some random libraries you only can link it with trusted static libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check out [TaLoS](https://github.com/lsds/TaLoS/), which seems to be doing what you want:

TaLoS is a TLS library that allows existing applications (with an OpenSSL/LibreSSL interface) to securely terminate their TLS connection inside an Intel SGX enclave. The code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/lsds/TaLoS/).

There also is a [technical report](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/research/technicalreports/2017/DTRS17-5.pdf) containing details about the architecture and performance results.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your setting is that you are not using the trusted version of OpenSSL. There are a few different libraries that support TLS inside the enclave. Intel has an implementation of OpenSSL for enclave [GitHub](https://github.com/intel/intel-sgx-ssl). I have created a short installation guide using their docs [Here](https://github.com/Behnam-Shobiri/SGXSSL-lib/blob/master/SSL%20library%20with%20SGX/Configure_VS.md).

However, the Intel version has some limitations such as they are not supporting ending the TLS connection inside the enclave; rather, they are supporting the crypto functions. There are some other libraries that support networking features but they are mainly not updated.